# Bytes in serial code to an array on Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, serial-port

I've read with a logic analyzer a TX of a controller. I know that it works at 1200 Baud and I have identified the frames according to this photo:

[Frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOCJu.jpg)

I have identified in the frame:

- 1byte - Always 54
- 2byte - Sequential, ++ per frame
- 3byte - Always 0
- 4, 5 and 6byte - Data
- 7byte - Always 0
- 8, 9, 10 and 11- Data
- 12, 13, 14 and 15- They vary (I understand that 15 is a checksum)

I cannot identify the checksum (I suspect Checksum8 Xor due to its similarity to another controller).

I try to take each byte with Arduino to a position of an Array, knowing that the first byte is constant (54) and the frame is always the same length.

Could it be that as the Arduino loop being faster than Serial it duplicates the data in all positions of each Array?

Looking for information I have read that when I make a Serial.print it works correctly (each byte is not repeated, but when I write an array with while (Serial.available ()) it fails.

I leave some frames obtained through arduino with:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(1200);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    int test= Serial1.read();
    Serial.println(test);
  }

}
```

54  154 0   84  84  84  0   84  84  84  84  201 133 84  224

54  155 0   89  89  89  0   89  89  89  89  206 138 89  233

54  156 0   2   2   2   0   2   2   2   2   119 51  2   238

54  157 0   7   7   7   0   7   7   7   7   124 56  7   239

54  158 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   117 49  0   236

54  159 0   5   5   5   0   5   5   5   5   122 54  5   229

Any help is welcome
Thank you very much

Comment: When you try to put it in an array you fail you say.  Post that code if you want help with it.  Perhaps someone an help you figure out where you went wrong.  If you just want someone to show you how to read into an array then please chrck any of the hundreds of tutorials already on the internet on that topic.

Comment: You've deducted the third byte as always zero, but it's highly plausible that it's just the upper part of a short (little endian encoding). As a little general hint, if you're trying to reverse engineer a protocol, try to influence the data which you're suspected to be send. As example: You've a thermometer, increase it's temperature (e.g. by touching) and watch which numbers increase. PS: Just taking a glance at the data you'll see that the bytes (3;5) and (7;10) and the second last always have the same value.